# Synchronize parent and child without semaphores

Tags: c++, c, process, pipe, fork

(no semaphores, or threading, just processes)

I want to read data from a file in parent and pass it to child through pipe.
Suppose data in file is

```
Is
This
Possible?
```

now after reading "`Is`" through pipe

1. How would child know that new data "`This`" has been passed and should be read
2. What would be the terminating condition after reading "`Possible?`" through pipe, so that child can terminate after reading all the data Parent wanted to pass

(Doing it without using semaphores or threads, just plain processes i-e forking)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: C or C++? They are different languages. Please pick one.

Comment: @mindriot Some questions apply equally to both languages and this is one of them. It asks about pipe I/O and the answer will be very similar in both cases.

Comment: `EOF` does not work for you?

Comment: The read end of a pipe blocks when there is no data available for input.  The read end of a pipe indicates EOF when the last process closes the write end of the pipe.  The only tricky bit is that if you request to read 256 bytes and three short lines are available, all three will be read at once.  On the other hand, if you have two pipes, one from child to parent and one from parent to child, then you can create synchronous half-duplex communication and avoid that problem — though you get some others instead (but they probably don't matter to you).

Comment: Have tried EOF, a separate key, sleep but nothing's working

Comment: Maybe you should post your fork, pipe creation, and I/O code. If the pipe is defined correctly, you shouldn't be experiencing these problems. If you're using `fork` and `pipe(2)`, using the file descriptor for the correct "side" of the pipe can be tricky, particularly if you need two pipes [one to send data to the child and the second to get data back]

Answer (score 1):

A parent writing to a *file* and the child reading from it would require the synchronization you're thinking of. That is, if parent has only written the 1st line and child has read it, but parent has *not* written line 2, child *will* get a premature EOF.

But, a *pipe* does not.

A pipe stays open until the parent/sender closes it [or child terminates]. So, the child can just read in a loop until it receives EOF.

The child will automatically block in the read if no data is available but will *not* get EOF prematurely. If you want, the child can do `select(2)` or `poll(2)` to check for data being available but I hardly think that's necessary.

The child will *not* get EOF until the parent has sent all the data *and* closed its end of the pipe.

So, no synchronization is needed.

On the other side, we may have a parent that sends *lots* of data quickly and the child is reading slowly (i.e.) falls behind a bit. Eventually, the [kernel] pipe buffer gets "full" and the parent write will block until the child has been able to "catch up" and drain some of the data. Thus, no data is "lost".

Comment: I think you may need to reword your first sentence.  A file stays open until it is closed too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read a fixed amount of data using fairly ubiquitous `read()` or `fread()` API, and use the fact that these will either block until more data is available or signal end-of-file conditions. This is the most straightforward way to pipe data into child processes: the child simply reads from `stdin` like an ordinary file, until it encounters the 'end-of-file' condition.

Alternatively, for a more responsive/performant design (or when dealing with hardware that signals on file objects) you need:

1. Enable support for nonblocking I/O
2. Monitor your input file descriptor/handle (the read side of the pipe) using `select()` like API
3. Integrate with an event loop (or write a simple one yourself)
4. Be able to deal with unexpected amounts of data available.
5. Be able to deal with errors from `read()`/`fread()` and friends, in particular `EAGAIN`.
6. And be able to deal with end-of-file conditions.

Wiring this up means delving into OS specific APIs, but fortunately it's also a common enough task that plenty of toolkit libraries (e.g. libuv, Qt) exist and provide consistent abstraction/higher level API.